# Producer / Consumer implementation for Parallel Processing in the TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

I've stripped this down to its bare bones removing stopping/cancellation logic etc... to keep it simple.

The `Producer` is a very simple class containing a timer. At regular intervals  the `TimerOnElapsed` will let the host now that it has another batch of items available. The onus is on the host to pull that next batch using `GetNextBatch()`.

```
public class Producer
{
    public event EventHandler BatchAvailable; 
    private readonly Timer timer;
    private int i;

    public Producer()
    {
        i = 1;
        timer = new Timer(5000);
        timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BatchAvailable != null)
            BatchAvailable(sender , e);
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetNextBatch()
    {
        var range = Enumerable.Range(i, i + 50).ToList();
        i = i + 50;
        return range;
    }
}
```

The `Consumer` class uses a `Concurrent.BlockingCollection<T>` to pass objects to a Parallel `ForEach` loop. The `Consumer` is **READY** for the next batch each time it empties the blocking collection of the existing batch.

```
public class Consumer
{
    private TaskFactory _factory;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<int> _entries;

    public Consumer()
    {
        _entries = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {

        _factory = new TaskFactory();

        try
        {
            _factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(
                    _entries.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
                    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 },
                    ProcessEntry
                    );
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException oce) { }
    }

    public void Add(int entry)
    {
        _entries.Add(entry);
    }

    public bool Ready
    {
        get { return (_entries.Count == 0); }
    }

    private void ProcessEntry(int entry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", entry);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

The `Host` is a class containing each of the above. It orchestrates communication between the two. Each time the `Producer` says it has another batch available, the host checks to see if the `Consumer` is ready, and if so, retrieves the batch and passes it on.

```
public class Host
{
    private Producer _producer;
    private Consumer _consumer;

    public Host()
    {
        _producer = new Producer();
        _producer.BatchAvailable += (s,e) => ProducerOnBatchAvailable();
        _consumer = new Consumer();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _producer.Start();
        _consumer.Start();
    }

    private void ProducerOnBatchAvailable()
    {
        if (!_consumer.Ready) return;
        Console.WriteLine("Producer is ready for another Batch...");
        var batch = _producer.GetNextBatch().ToList();
        batch.ForEach(_consumer.Add);
    }
}
```

I've tested this a couple of times and it behaves as I'd expect. The throttling of batch sizes and the max parallelism in the P-`ForEach` loop also works. And in my larger example I have a number of other `Players` that hand entry along to the next step in the pipeline by way of more events and blocking collections.

However, I'm a bit irked by the fact that I never need to call the `BlockCollection<T>.CompletedAdding()`. Is this bad practice? Do I have any potential problems leaving the blocking collection in the WAIT state for long periods of time?

In the real example the producer will be querying a DB queue which could potentially have no work in it, so the `BlockingCollection` could sit there for hours overnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never added a second answer before, but I feel it's somewhat different from the other one and a bit more complete to address your questions. I've added `Stop()` methods and process those as such in the both the producer, consumer and host as such:

Producer:

```
public sealed class Producer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer timer = new Timer(5000);

    private int i = 1;

    private bool disposed;

    public event EventHandler BatchAvailable;

    public void Start()
    {
        this.timer.Elapsed += this.TimerOnElapsed;
        this.timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.timer.Stop();
        this.timer.Elapsed -= this.TimerOnElapsed;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Stop();
        this.timer.Dispose();
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetNextBatch()
    {
        var range = Enumerable.Range(this.i, this.i + 50);

        this.i += 50;
        return range;
    }

    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var batchAvailable = this.BatchAvailable;

        if (batchAvailable != null)
        {
            batchAvailable(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
public sealed class Consumer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<int> entries = new BlockingCollection<int>();

    private readonly TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory();

    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

    private Task task;

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            this.tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            this.task = this.factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(
                        this.entries.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
                        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, CancellationToken = tokenSource.Token },
                        (i, loopState) =>
                        {
                            if (!this.tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                ProcessEntry(i);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.entries.CompleteAdding();
                                loopState.Stop();
                            }
                        });
                },
                this.tokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oce);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public void Add(int entry)
    {
        this.entries.Add(entry);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.task == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.tokenSource.Cancel();
        while (!this.task.IsCanceled)
        {
        }

        this.task.Dispose();
        this.tokenSource.Dispose();
        this.task = null;
    }

    public bool Ready
    {
        get
        {
            return this.entries.Count == 0;
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessEntry(int entry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", entry);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

and Host:

```
public sealed class Host : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Producer producer = new Producer();

    private readonly Consumer consumer = new Consumer();

    private bool disposed;

    public Host()
    {
        this.producer.BatchAvailable += (s, e) => this.ProducerOnBatchAvailable();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.producer.Start();
        this.consumer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.producer.Stop();
        this.consumer.Stop();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Stop();
        this.producer.Dispose();
        this.consumer.Dispose();
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    private void ProducerOnBatchAvailable()
    {
        if (!this.consumer.Ready)
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Producer is ready for another Batch...");

        var batch = this.producer.GetNextBatch().ToList();

        batch.ForEach(this.consumer.Add);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly similar to the full version I have. Like i said in the original post, I stripped out a lot of the stop, disposal & task cancellation code for brevity...

However I see you didn't make any modification to the `BlockCollection<T>` population or enumeration. And that you haven't included any reference to the CompletedAdding Method.

Comment: Read closer - there is indeed a reference to `CompleteAdding` in the main loop of the producer.

Comment: aah... I see what you've done there... ok thanks. I'll go and integrate that change and do some more testing. Appreciate the feedback. Cheers.

Comment: @EoinCampbell best of luck with it!

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of being thread-safe, you should replace this:

```
    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BatchAvailable != null)
            BatchAvailable(sender , e);
    }
```

with this:

```
    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var batchAvailable = this.BatchAvailable;

        if (batchAvailable != null)
        {
            batchAvailable(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

Reason being, accessing the event field "raw", you may wind up with it going `null` between the `if` and the invocation itself.